# I am unable to login again to my Python form after logging out

Tags: python, mysql, forms, sockets

Good Day,
I am trying to create a form in Python that stores data in a MySQL database. However when I logout of the form and I want to log back in I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ariel\OneDrive\Documents\400L\SIWES\NH PYTHON\PYTHON\ecommerce.py", line 869, in authenticate
    data = self.s.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

This is the line of code the error is referencing:

```
    def authenticate(self):
        username = self.username_Entry_login.get()
        password = self.pass_Entry_login_1.get()

        data = self.s.recv(1024)
        message = [username, password, "login"]
        self.s.send(str.encode(json.dumps(message)))
        resp = self.s.recv(1024)
        result = json.loads(bytes.decode(resp))


        print(result)

        if result:
            messagebox.showinfo("", "Login Successful!")
            self.show_frame(self.user)
        if username == "admin" and password == "admin":
            messagebox.showinfo("", "Login Successful!")
            self.show_frame(self.admin)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid username or password")

        self.conn.commit()
        self.s.close()
```

I had established a socket connection in another with this portion of code

```
import mysql.connector
import socket
import json  

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", database="commercedb", user="root", password="")
cursor = conn.cursor()

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host = ""  
port = 8000  
server.bind((host, port)) 
server.listen(5)


while True: 
    print("Listening for a client...")
    client, addr = server.accept()  
    print("Accepted connection from ", addr)
    client.send(str.encode(
        "Welcome to my server!")) 

    while True:  
        data = client.recv(
            1024)  
        command = json.loads(bytes.decode(data))
        if "register" in command:
            command.remove("register")
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO commerce_users (user_id,username,email,password,reg_status) VALUES('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(
                    *command))
            cursor.execute("SELECT * from commerce_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")

            resp = cursor.fetchall() 
            conn.commit()
            print("Sending registration response...")
            client.send(str.encode(json.dumps(
                resp))) 

            client.close()
        elif "login" in command:
            command.remove("login")
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM commerce_users WHERE username='{}' AND password='{}'".format(*command))
            resp = cursor.fetchall()
            conn.commit()
            print("Sending login response...")
            client.send(str.encode(json.dumps(resp)))
            client.close()
        conn.close()
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: After the first loop, in either case you call a `client.close()` which closes the socket. So in the subsequent call to `data = client.recv(1024)` your client isn't able to receive data because you have already closed it.

Comment: @AndreaPollini I commented those lines out but I still receive the same error

Comment: Your authenticate method is called when the socket is connected? You must use a debugger and step through the code in order to see if your logic is correct.